# How to populate Map[string,Dataframe] as a column in a Dataframe in scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, dictionary

I have a `Map[String, Dataframe]`. I want to combine all the data inside that Map into a single Dataframe. Can a dataframe have a column of Map datatype?

```scala
def sample(dfs : Map[String,Dataframe]): Dataframe =
{
.........
}
```

Example:

**DF1**

```
id name age
1  aaa  23
2  bbb  34
```

**DF2**

```
game  time  score
ludo  10    20
rummy 30    40
```

I pass the above two DFs as Map to the function.
Then put data of the each dataframes into a single column of the output dataframe as json format.

**out DF**

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| column1                                                                              |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| [{"id":"1","name":"aaa","age":"23"},{"id":21","name":"bbb","age":"24"}]               |
| [{"game":"ludo","time":"10","score":"20"},{"game":"rummy","time":"30","score":"40"}]  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: could you provide example of what you want? \n Dataframes support struct and array types not maps

Comment: I want to put data of multiple dataframes to a single dataframe .If it does not support map then how can I get value of each input Dataframe as struct column to output dataframe

Comment: How should the dataframes be combined? Can you give an example?

Comment: I have edited the question with an example kindly check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking to generate one row per dataframe. Be careful, if one of the dataframes is large enough so that it cannot be contained in one single executor, this code will break.

Let's first generate data and the map `dfs` of type `Map[String, DataFrame]`.

```scala
val df1 = Seq((1, "aaa", 23), (2, "bbb", 34)).toDF("id", "name", "age")
val df2 = Seq(("ludo", 10, 20), ("rummy", 10, 40)).toDF("game", "time", "score")
dfs = Seq(df1, df2)
```

Then, for each dataframe of the map, we generate two columns. `big_map` associates each column name of the dataframe to its value (cast in string to have a consistent type). `df` simply contains the name of the dataframe. We then union all the dataframes with `reduce` and group by `name` (that's the part where every single dataframe ends up entirely in one row, and therefore one one executor).

```scala
dfs
    .toSeq
    .map{ case (name, df) => df
        .select(map(
             df.columns.flatMap(c => Seq(lit(c), col(c).cast("string"))) : _*
        ) as "big_map")
        .withColumn("df", lit(name))}
    .reduce(_ union _)
    .groupBy("df")
    .agg(collect_list('big_map) as "column1")
    .show(false)
```

```
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|df |column1                                                                            |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|df0|[{id -> 1, name -> aaa, age -> 23}, {id -> 2, name -> bbb, age -> 34}]             |
|df1|[{game -> ludo, time -> 10, score -> 20}, {game -> rummy, time -> 10, score -> 40}]|
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution specific to your use-case:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql._

def sample(dfs : Map[String, DataFrame])(implicit spark: SparkSession): DataFrame =
  dfs
    .values
    .foldLeft(spark.emptyDataFrame)((acc, df) => acc.union(df))
```

The spark session is required to create the empty DataFrame accumulator to fold on.

Alternatively if you can guarantee the `Map` is non empty.

```scala
def sample(dfs : Map[String, DataFrame]): DataFrame =
  dfs
    .values
    .reduce((acc, df) => acc.union(df))
```

Comment: can you please check the question I have added an example now.Each input dataframe which I get has diff schemas so I want the data of an entire input dataframe to be populated as a column ,so my output dataframe has data of each input dataframe in one column